# Android Cmake Error: os_defines.h:39:22: fatal error: features.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated

Tags: android, compilation, android-ndk, cmake

How can I tell cmake to point to the Android compiler in the NDK?

Below is my CMAKE file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)

set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Android)

set(CMAKE_ANDROID_NDK /home/c/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle)

set(ANDROID_NDK  /home/c/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle)
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_API 21)


SET(CMAKE_SYSROOT /home/c/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/)


# build native_app_glue as a static lib
add_library(app-glue STATIC
            ${ANDROID_NDK}/sources/android/native_app_glue/android_native_app_glue.c)

# now build app's shared lib
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++11 ")

add_library(native-activity SHARED
            main.cpp)

target_include_directories(native-activity PRIVATE
                           ${ANDROID_NDK}/sources/android/native_app_glue)

# add lib dependencies
target_link_libraries(native-activity
                      android
                      app-glue
                      EGL
                      GLESv1_CM
                      log)
```

I get the following error:

> In file included from
>   /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5/bits/c++config.h:482:0,
>                    from /usr/include/c++/5/initializer_list:41,
>                    from /home/c/AndroidStudioProjects/NativeActivity4/app/src/main/cpp/main.cpp:19:
>   /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5/bits/os_defines.h:39:22: fatal
>   error: features.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.

It is using my standard linux compiler. How can I tell cmake to point to the Android compiler in the NDK? I do not think a standalone toolchain in necessary for this but that variable is available. I am doing his in netbeans if that matters.

Comment: C++ compiler is set via *CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER* variable. Every tutorial about cross-compiling notes that.

Comment: Thank you. I tried using ANDROID_CXX_COMPILER and wondered why it did not work. Upon trying CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER  I get:   fatal error: initializer_list: No such file or directory
 #include <initializer_list>
                            ^
compilation terminated. I assume I used the wrong android compiler. I used the one by the name of: arm-linux-androideabi-g++ located here: ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++

Comment: That is the first include in my .cpp file. So nothing is found.

Comment: There are many ready toolchains for Android in the net. Why do not use one of them instead of trying to adjust all cross-compile things manually?

Comment: i wanted to run the native android activity in netbeans instead of android studio. However, obviously this is to much of a task for me. What do you mean 'ready toolchains,' the ones that come in the ndk directory?